# Laravel eloquent table joined to itself, how to get 1 array with all values

Tags: laravel

I am using a table employee that is joined to itself for the manager.

```
Employee
id
name
manager_id (FK to Employee)
```

I am using the following model for Employee:

```
public function my_employees()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Employee', 'manager_id');
}

public function my_manager()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee', 'manager_id');
```

It is working fine because I can use the my_employees function on an employee and it will get me all the records linked to this employee.

Now I would like to get a table with all the employees where the column manager_id is replaced by manager_name. How can I achieve this with Eloquent?

Not using Eloquent, I do:

```
$employee = DB::table('employee')
            ->select('employee.id', 'employee.name', 'employee.manager_id','manager.name AS manager_name')
            ->join('employee AS manager', 'employee.manager_id','=','manager.id');
```

This gets me of course what I want but I would like to understand how to do it with Eloquent only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly the same way.

```
$employees = Employee::select('employee.id', 'employee.name', 'employee.manager_id', 'manager.name AS manager_name')
    ->join('employee AS manager', 'employee.manager_id', '=', 'manager.id')
    ->get();
```

You could also do this shown below. But then you need to access the manager name from the relationship object.

```
$employees = Employee::with('my_manager')->get();

foreach($employees as $employee) {
    echo $employee->my_manager->name;
}
```

**Edit**

You can add any constraint to the eager loaded relationship.

```
$employees = Employee::with(['my_manager' => function($query) {
    $query->select('manager_id', 'name');
}])->get();
```

Comment: Hi, did some tests with what you suggested and I start understanding how this with is working. The thing is that now I get a table with the list of records and one of the column is called my_manager. In this column, I get all the fields from the manager. Is it possible to get all the fields from the employee and then only 1 column is added with the name of the manager?

Comment: @Richard yes you can. I've updated my answer with what you've asked. Similarly you can change the constraints just like you would on a normal eloquent query.

Comment: No, sorry but with what you sent me, I get all the time my_manager: null

Comment: @Richard my bad i forgot the relationship key. The loaded relationship always needs the key to be selected. So along with the `name` it needs `manager_id`. Can you try that.